# Permission Error Handler - Bot Crashes how to use try catch properly

Tags: discord.js

I want it so my bot can only send embeds in specific channels with the permissions granted but if a user sends the message in a channel where the permissions are not granted the bot stops working and cuts off. I am trying to make it so a try catch works so even if an error is thrown it continues to work, the error I am getting is "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions - I want to be able to ignore this error.

```
function catchErr (err, emessage, a){
console.log("Someone tried to use the embed in the");}




    let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'discordbot ':
            try {
            const discordbot = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('My Discord Bot*')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Test Bot:', value: 'Test' },
            message.channel.send(discordbot );
        } catch (err) {
            catchErr(err, message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.send` returns a `Promise`, if you want to catch errors you can either go for `Promise.catch` or use `async / await` (this requires your top level function to be async)

```js
// Using Promise.catch
const catchErr = err => {
  console.log(err)
}

message.channel.send(embed).catch(catchErr)

// Using async / await
try {
  await message.channel.send(embed)
} catch(err) {
  catchErr(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendMessage(message,content){
        const permissions = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (permissions.has("SEND_MESSAGES")){
            if(content){
                message.channel.send(content);
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("[ERR] no msg perms")
            message.author.send("I can't send messages on this channel or guild!, Try another channel or contact the server staff to check bot's permissions.");
        }
    }
```